# $F =\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ $E = \{a + bw + cw^2: a,b,c \in \Bbb Q \} \subseteq \Bbb C$ Prove $E \cong F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

I have a ring $F =\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ and a set $E = \{a + bw + cw^2: a,b,c \in \Bbb Q \} \subseteq \Bbb C$. $w = \frac{-1}{2} + \frac{ \sqrt 3}{2}i$. I need to show that these are isomorphic.

So I define a function $f: E \to F$. I need to show first that every $\forall x,y \in E, f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and $f(xy) = f(x) f(y) $. Then prove that $f$ a bijection.

So $x+y = (a+a') + (b+b')w + (c+c)w^2$ and $xy = (a + bw + cw^2)(a' + b'w + c'w^2)$. The question here for me is what are $f(x+y)$ and $f(xy)$? Is it just the same polynomial because of how $F$ is defined to be a ring of polynomials over the rationals?

I'm a little confused as to how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Complex numbers can be defined as $R[x]/(x^2+1)$, and a subset of that of interest is $Q[x]/(x^2+1)$. Note that this second field can also be expressed as $\{a+bi: a,b\in Q\}$. Now look at your polynomial. What are it's roots? It may be simpler to look at isomorphisms for the first, then apply the same technique to the second.

Comment: They can't be isomorphic. Assume you would have ring-isomorphism mapping $E$ to $F$. In particular, they would define a linear (vector space) isomorphism. But the dimension of $E$ is 3 while the dimension of $F$ is $2$.

Comment: @SommeGuy I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be seeing with the roots. So would we then be taking $f((a+a') + (b+b')i)$? I'm very confused here.

Comment: @Some guy. I know that the root of the polynomial is just $w$, right?

Comment: Yes, and it may be simpler computationally to get a proof in the i case then do the w. But user159517 also mentions the mismatch dimensions, and I agree with that, but if you fix b in the E set to zero, it should be isomorphic.

Comment: Ok. That's just how my book had it written I get that. I will fix it. Now how do I compute $f((a+a′)+(b+b′)i)$ though and show that it is $f(a+bi) + f(a'+b'i)$? What exactly should I say $f$ does? @SommeGuy

Comment: @user159517 $E$ is dimension $2$ also. The "$cw^2$" is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The map $f: \mathbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow F$ given by $f : x \mapsto \omega$ clearly defines a surjective homomorphism. It's kernel is the ideal generated by $x^2+x+1$.